# Adding image next to text in table

Tags: tables, graphics, wrapfigure

I have a text in a 3 row table like as follows

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{3in}
\centering 
\includegraphics{style3color.png}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{tabular*}{7in}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
a \\
b \\
c  \\
\end{tabular*}
```

I want to insert an image that spans across all the rows in the 2nd column. What's the best way to do it?

As you can see from above I have used `wrapfig` package to wrap this table around the image. It works but the image does not come to the center. It starts from b to end way below c.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find a solution when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to put a table and a figure side to side (or two any objects, by the way) an easy solution is to enclose each one into a minipage of given widths, and put `\hfill` between minipages if you want the objects be "full justified" (i.e: aligned with page margins). Give each minipage `[c]` option to vertically align them.

In your case (I included `\fbox` only to make visible the size of each minipage and `\hrulefill` instead of `\hfill` to make visible the vertical centering):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    a \\
    b \\
    c  \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
}\hrulefill
\fbox{
  \begin{minipage}[c]{2cm}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{star.mps}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to insert a `tabularx` that fits within the line (or `7in`, depending on your requirement) and `\smash` the contents of your image to make it fit within your parameters vertically. Here's a quick example of what I mean:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{graphicx,tabularx}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{lX}
  a \\ b \\
  c & \hfill
    \smash{\raisebox{-.3\normalbaselineskip}{%
      \includegraphics[height=3\normalbaselineskip]{example-image-a}}}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

`\hfill` pushes the contents of the `X`-column to the right (as it seems like you're after an `r`-column, but it may not be necessary). The image height is forced to `3\normalbaselineskip` which makes it fit within 3 lines of the table. However, it's moved down slightly (`.3\normalbaselineskip`) to accommodate for the fact that it's actually placed on the baseline, which doesn't center it vertically across the three rows. `\smash` removes all vertical height, making it span more than one row (similar to what `\multirow` from the [`multirow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow) would do).

`tabularx` is not necessary, but it may help in these situations, depending on your actual application/usage.